# difference between gethostbyname and gethostbynamel

Tags: php

What is difference between gethostbyname() and gethostbynamel() PHP function?
As both returns A record for a domain name. Also which one perform better?

Comment: read this article:http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

based on the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php) `gethostbynamel` returns the full list of resolved ip address of a specific hostname. where `gethostbyname` only returns one.

for an example try `gethostbynamel('www.google.com');` so you will see a list returned.

Comment: Some times `gethostbynamel()` return empty, however `gethostbyname()` return the value passed.

Example: ``gethostbynamel('ns1.cocacola.com');``